# Need access to a global generic list in all Silverlight views

Tags: silverlight, class, properties

I have a generic list that gets loaded when a certain view is first used. Now I need this list to be accessed from all views in my project.

I've been experimenting using a Public Property in the App class. Problem is, I cannot seem to access that property from the other classes/view code (trying App.Current).

How can I access a public property generic list defined in the App class?

This is in VB.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this sort of thing is to create a static class (called "Globals" or "Config" or something like that), and create a static property which contains the list you want to reference.  So it might look something like this:

```
public static class Globals
{
    public static List<Customer> AllCustomers {get; set; }
}
```

Or in VB.NET:

```
Private Shared m_AllCustomers as List(of Customer)
Public Shared Property AllCustomers As List(of Customer)
   Get
      Return m_AllCustomers
   End Get
   Set(ByVal Value as List(of Customer))
      m_AllCustomers = Value
   End Set
End Property
```

And you can then get/set that property from wherever you need it:

```
Globals.AllCustomers = new List<Customer>();
```

Or:

```
 Globals.AllCustomers = New List(Of Customer)
```

Of course, globals like this aren't generally a great idea, but sometimes they're the simplest solution.  It's also a good idea, in my opinion, to put them in classes rather than in VB.NET modules, as it adds a namespace to the value, rather than having them in the global namespace.  That helps a little bit with modularity.

If you insist on making this a property of App.Current, you need to cast App.Current to the actual class you've created, namely:

```
var allCustomers = ((App)App.Current).AllCustomers;
```

But I generally avoid adding these sorts of properties to my App class, because it makes them harder to test and breaks the idea of Single Responsibility.

Comment: Took me a bit to realize that in VB I can do this with a simple Module as I don't think static classes exist in VB. But your answer got me looking into this more, thanks.

Comment: I should have remembered - in VB.NET, although a class can't be static, class members can be: but the keyword is "Shared" not "static".  I'll update my answer.